# How can I change the text with a button?

Tags: android, textview

I am starting off with a simple app when a button changes the text I want to change it from saying 'hello world' to 'hello brody' when I push a button here is what I got

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.helloworld.app.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New ToggleButton"
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

what can I do so that it changes the text ?

Comment: post your activity code what have you done.

Comment: What you want to change `ToggleButton` text or `TextView` text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    TextView textView;
    ToggleButton toggleButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn, boolean checked)
                {
                    textView.setText(checked ? "hello brody" : "hello world");
                }               
            }
        );
    }
}
```

To jibe with the layout xml you've provided, you need to add the following line to the `TextView` tag:

```
android:id="@+id/textView"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this. It would help you

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            yourTextViewObject.setText("Hello World");
        } else {
            yourTextViewObject.setText("Hello Brody");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi have a look and try with the given code here

```
ToggleButton toggleButton= (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);

    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {
               //do accordingly
            } else {
                  //do accordingly
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: how do i put these in what file

Comment: i dont know where to put this where do i put it in